# Is it possible to dynamically add a pane in Highstock/Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to dynamically add or delete panes in high-stocks?

For instance I want to give the user a choice whether he wants to see more than 2 panes or not (in eg: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pane is additional yAxis, which can be added by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis()

Comment: Tx @Sebastian. Also as a followup, is it possible to delete the panes dynamically? Just asked a new question at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615287/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-pane-in-highstock-highcharts