# Is it possible to remove a pane in highstock/highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Suppose I have two panes in my highstock, can I remove one of the panes dynamically. So if I click on a pane, I should be able to trap the event alongwith the id of the pane(yaXis) and subsequently delete the axis alongwith its series.
I have added the panes dynamically like following( so I axis have Id etc. with me)

```
chartX.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
                    id: studyName,
                    title: {
                        text: studyText
                    },
                    isX: false,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: '#08F',
                    //opposite: true,
                    top: startHeight,
                    height: 100,
                    offset: 0
                });
                var chartToUpdate=chartX.addSeries({
                        name: 'ADBE',
                        id: 'studyNew',
                        color: 'black',
                        data: studyData,
                        yAxis: studyName
                    });
                    $("#selectStudy").append("<option value='"+countNoOfStudiesAdded+"'>"+studyName+"</option>")
                }
```

Is it possible to delete the pane as mentioned above. Any other method that can help achieve dynamic removal of the pane will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the solution by tinkering... 
The best one was by adding the events such that whenever I click on the legend of the series, its pane is removed.

```
var chartToUpdate=chartX.addSeries({
                        name: 'ADBE',
                        id: studyName,
                        color: 'black',
                        data: studyData,
                        yAxis: studyName,
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function(event) {
                                this.yAxis.remove();
                                countNoOfStudiesAdded--;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

If someone wants the exact answer to my question then the solution is to have a dropdown select/option and a button. Once the button is clicked, we find the pane to be deleted from dropdown and then delete it as follows:

```
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        if($("#selectStudy").val()!=0) {
            var studyToDelete=chartX.get($("#selectStudy option:selected").text());
            while(studyToDelete!=null) {
                studyToDelete.remove();
                $("#selectStudy option:selected").remove()
                studyToDelete=chartX.get($("#selectStudy option:selected").text());
            }
        }
    });
```

where `id` of `button` is `remove`, `id` of `selection` dropdown list is `selectStudy`. So we find all the series attached to the pane having same id as that of `yAxis` ad delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axis.remove() function to remove axis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.remove()